# Suavizar animação de elemento tipo balançar via CSS transform

Tags: javascript, css3, animação

O conceito que se está a tentar atingir é o movimento continuo sobre o eixo do X entre um valor e a sua representação em negativo:

[image: Gráfico com onda de efeito desejado]

Até ao momento, esse conceito tem uma falha, a animação é realizada de 0 graus até ao valor facultado, mas depois ao recuar para o mesmo valor em negativo, existe um pulo para os 0 graus e só depois é que anima para o valor facultado. O mesmo acontece ao voltar ao valor positivo:

[image: Gráfico com onda do efeito problemático]

Ver exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/1a2vou6L/)

```js
$.fn.animateRotate = function(angle, duration, easing, complete) {
  var args = $.speed(duration, easing, complete);
  var step = args.step;
  return this.each(function(i, e) {
 args.complete = $.proxy(args.complete, e);
 args.step = function(now) {
   $.style(e, 'transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
   if (step) return step.apply(e, arguments);
 };

 $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: angle}, args);
  });
};

// animate snowman
var d = 5;

function jingle() {
  $("#snowman").animateRotate(d, {
    duration: 1337,
    easing: 'linear',
    complete: function () {
      jingle(d = -d);
    }
  });
}

jingle();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="snowman" alt="snowman" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmNNj.png">
```

### O objeto a animar

A imagem em baixo é o objeto que se pretende animar conforme podem analisar nas demonstrações.

[image: Snowman, who else?]

## Pergunta

Como posso suavizar o efeito de forma a chegar à curva de animação pretendida?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma sugestão é confiar essa animação no CSS, via `transition` do `transform: rotate()`.

Acho que o jQuery pode ser simplificado para:

```
var ang = -5;
var el = document.querySelector('img');

setInterval(function () {
    ang = -ang;
    el.style[prefix + 'transform'] = 'rotate(' + ang + 'deg)';
}, 1000);
```

e o CSS

```
img {
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

e juntando uma correção para browsers que precisem de sufixo pode usar-se

```
var prefix = (function () {
    var styles = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement, ''),
        pre = (Array.prototype.slice.call(styles)
            .join('')
            .match(/-(moz|webkit|ms)-/) || (styles.OLink === '' && ['', 'o']))[1];
    if (pre == 'moz') return '';
    return '-' + pre + '-';
})();
```

(adaptado / importado do blog do David Walsh)

Nesse caso a animação ficaria: **http://jsfiddle.net/k4fp79w1/**

Answer (score 7):

Utilizando `@keyframes` junto com a propriedade `animation` para ter controle sobre a animação.

[Keyframes na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

[Animações na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_animations)

---

Para esse caso, somente com CSS, uma possível solução seria:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes snowman {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(4deg)}
    to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg)}
}

@keyframes snowman {
    from {transform: rotate(4deg)}
    to   {transform: rotate(-4deg)}
}

#snowman {
    -webkit-animation: snowman 2s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
            animation: snowman 2s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<img id="snowman" alt="snowman" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmNNj.png">
```

Answer (score 4):

Esquecendo um pouco a parte de código, vamos pensar no seguinte:

- Quando um objeto arredondado apoiado no chão gira, ele também se move para o lado correspondente ao giro.
- Além disso, a sombra não gira junto, mas sim se projeta conforme a forma do objeto. Neste caso, a sombra é uma "mancha genérica", pois se trata de um desenho apenas, mas espera-se que ela se movimente de acordo com o objeto.

Partindo disso, dividi o boneco em questão em duas imagens: O próprio, e a sombra.

Como já respondido pelo @Renan (que também recebeu meu *upvote*), *keyframes* são um caminho interessante para este tipo de animação, pois serão gerenciados usualmente por um subsistema separado do *browser*, provavelmente numa *thread* separada do JS, garantindo uma animação mais fluida, ao mesmo tempo sobrecarregando menos a aplicação principal (mas observe a "nota 2" no rodapé da questão, para ver os pontos contra).

Juntando tudo isto, segue o resultado (o *vendor-prefix* atrapalha a elegância um pouco):

```css
@-webkit-keyframes snowman { from { -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px) rotate(-10deg) }
                             to   { -webkit-transform: translateX( 20px) rotate( 10deg) } }
@-webkit-keyframes shadow  { from { -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px) }
                             to   { -webkit-transform: translateX( 10px) } }
@keyframes snowman         { from { transform: translateX(-20px) rotate(-10deg) }
                             to   { transform: translateX( 20px) rotate(  0deg) } }
@keyframes shadow          { from { transform: translateX(-10px) }
                             to   { transform: translateX( 10px) } }
#snowman { -webkit-animation: snowman 2s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
                   animation: snowman 2s alternate infinite ease-in-out; z-index:10; }
#shadow  { -webkit-animation: shadow  2s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
                   animation: shadow  2s alternate infinite ease-in-out; z-index: 0; }
#boneco { min-height: 350px } #boneco img { position: absolute; }
```

```html
<p>Aumente a janela ou use a barra de rolagem para ver o efeito.</p>
<div id="boneco">
  <img id="snowman" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRMcV.png">
  <img id="shadow"  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDz9I.png">
</div>
```

**Nota 1:** a resposta do @Sergio também é interessante para situações mais complexas em que o *keyframe* possa ser insuficiente, além de conter uma camada de compatibilização bem interessante.

**Nota 2:** dito isto, [aqui tem um artigo](http://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/) (en) que mostra que *keyframes* também tem seus problemas, e um deles é sincronização. Vale a pena dar uma lida.

Comment: Construíram esse boneco meio torto. Ele pende mais para a esquerda... :p

Comment: @bfavaretto sei que a observação tem um tom de brincadeira (baseada em fatos verídicos :P ), mas dá para usar ângulos diferentes em cada lado (por exemplo, -5 e 15 em vez de -10 e 10). Óbvio que num caso desses o certo é desentortar o boneco, mas acho que ele torto contribui para a dramatização da instabilidade infinita :)